# Use of hash (#) on OS X with UK MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I have MacVim on a UK MacBook Pro. I can use the hash on TextMate by typing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> but in vim this does not work. Do you know how I can type a hash using VIM on a UK MacBook Pro?

The problem is happening in any VI/VIM with a Mac with UK keyboard. If I am in insert mode, I type alt + 3 (hash char in a MacBook Pro UK keyboard) VI exists to insert mode.

Comment: I had this exact problem, threw the stupid US keyboard that came with the Mac in the bin and plugged a Windows keyboard with a £ sign into my Mac.  Worked great with vim! ;-)

Comment: Vim in Terminal.app or iTerm2.app or in MacVim? Do you have troubles with {[ and co as well or is it only #?

Comment: only with # and {[ are. I do not want to use a Windows keyboard!

Comment: c'on! Anyone using a mac with vim?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I've just come across this issue...

Answer (score 7):

If you're using iTerm2 then the left option acts as `+Esc` by default.

To fix this you can:

- Go into Preferences -> Profiles -> Default (or your profile) -> Keys
- In there you should see a section at the bottom called "Keyboard Behavior" and "Left option key acts as:"
- Select the 'Normal' radio button and you should find you can type the hash symbol.

[screenshot of iTerm2 preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpkyT.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal preferences. Select the current Profile and Keyboard. Disable the `Use Option as Meta key` preference shown here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> (aka opt) + <kbd>↓</kbd>.

I found this by looking at Terminal Preferences and going to the Keyboard options.  There's a list of keys and actions

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd + '\'
```

gets you a '#' when RDPing to Windows from a MBP with Apple UK External Keyboard under Lion, maybe try this for Vim?

Answer (score 0):

In newer Macs this issue is fixed. For older Macs you can map the # to a combination of keys. See the Vim wiki site.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem with iTerm2 (not Terminal) in MacOS Sierra. I tried remapping a modifier key in the settings ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElCyG.png)), so that 'Left Option' triggers 'Right Option'. So far it works, and can't see any side-effects.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Your answer seems legit, but it  is custom to include the solution in the answer itself just in case the URL you are referring to becomes inaccessible. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

2021: none of the above work for me, turn out Iterm2 set `Alt + Number` as shortcuts to switch panes in

```
Keys > Navigations Shortcuts > Shortcut to choose a split pane
```

Set it to `None` and it works again.

Comment: The new fancy touch bar is integrated with the standard Apple terminal, you need to have the left most button as option and then right option + 3 works, however I use often the meta key, so switching that key is a waste of time. Macs are becoming worse and worse for IT Unix peope

Answer (score 0):

I changed the keyboard layout from "British" to "British - PC".

**On Monterey, go to `System Preferences > Keyboard` then click the `+` and select "British - PC".**

Now `#` shows up next to the return key (where `\` used to be).

Note that this also remaps some other keys e.g. swapping `"` and `@`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to be able to use Option as Meta, and *also* to use Opt-3 as a # key, despite the two being nominally incompatible.

The solution may be found in Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys -> Key Mappings.

[image: The top half of the Key Mappings panel, showing the required mapping]

You may map Opt-3 to #, and it does exactly what I'm looking for: any other use of Option acts like Meta.  I can't refer to parameter 3 in bash with a single shortcut any more, but I never really did that anyway.